# How to find out which server my FQDN points to?

Tags: fqdn

My FQDN

```
https://dopsops.tech/
```

I dedicated time to some other project,how to find out which server I used.
Which commands should I use?
`curl -I` just gives content.

```
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report
```

How to find next server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the domain points to Cloudflare, you cannot see the final server IP without logging into Cloudflare dashboard.

Log in to Cloudflare, and go into DNS settings. There one can see the upstream server that hosts the domain.

Comment: Ok, I have private IP,what next?

Comment: Private IP are as they say.... Private, so not routable on internet. Are you located on the local network that or theses machines are on ?